# How can I compare two strings and try to print out comman latters but i could not avoid to repeat a latter more than once

Tags: java, string

I am comparing two strings and try to print out comman latters but i could not avoid to repeat a latter more than once. 
here is my code

```
public static String getCommonCharacters ( final String a, final String b){
    String result="";
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < b.length(); j++)
            if(a.charAt(i)==b.charAt(j)){
                result +=a.charAt(i);
            }
    } return result;
```

the problem is when a = "baac" and b =" fdeabac " then i get out = "aabaac" instead of "abc" or "bca" etc

Comment: Put the characters into `Set<Character>`s, use `aSet.retainAll(bSet)`, then put the remaining chars back into a String.

Comment: a functional equivalent of your code would be `return IntStream
                   .concat(a.chars(), b.chars())
                   .filter(e -> a.contains(String.valueOf((char)e)) &&
                           b.contains(String.valueOf((char)e)))
                   .distinct()
                   .mapToObj(e -> String.valueOf((char)e))
                   .collect(Collectors.joining());` but that's just a preference i guess. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change the `if` condition to:

```
if (a.charAt(i) == b.charAt(j) && 
     !result.contains(String.valueOf(a.charAt(i)))) { ... }
```

Thus, you only perform the statement:

```
result +=a.charAt(i);
```

if the accumulating string doesn't already contain the character.

Answer (score 0):

Working code with minor modification to yours:

```
public class StringCompare {
    public static String getCommonCharacters(final String a, final String b) {
        String result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b.length(); j++)
                if (a.charAt(i) == b.charAt(j)) {
                    result += a.charAt(i);
                }
        }
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(getCommonCharacters("baac", "fdeabac ").replaceAll(
                "(.)\\1{1,}", "$1")); // You could use regular expressions for
                                        // that. Removing repeated characters.
    }
}
```

Output:

> bac

Pattern explanation:

- "**(.)\1{1,}**" means any character (added to group 1) followed by itself at least once
- "**$1**" references contents of group 1

More about  [Regular Expressions Oracle Docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Answer (score 0):

Hier is another solution: create two new HashSet for each String which we change to charArray, then add them to hashSet with For loops,
retainAll() method provide  used to remove it's elements from a list that are not contained in the specified collection.@Java Doc by Oracle
Last For-Loop used to concatenate char as a strings.

```
    String str ="";

    Set<Character> s1 = new HashSet<Character>();
    Set<Character> s2 = new HashSet<Character>();
    for(char c:a.toCharArray()) s1.add(c);

    for(char c:b.toCharArray()) s2.add(c);

    s1.retainAll(s2);
    for(char s:s1) str +=s;

   return str;
```